# Xamarin TableView Height & Binding

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, prism

I understand how to configure a TableView to have uneven cells in order to have varying heights. I am currently experiencing an issue in which the content in my TableView cell is set through a Binding to my view model using the Prism MVVM framework.

```xml
<TableView HasUnevenRows="True"
           RowHeight="0">
    <TableRoot>
        <TableSection Title="Description">
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Text="{Binding CreateUser}"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding CreateTime}"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Description}"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </TableSection>
    </TableRoot>
</TableView>
```

I am currently using the `OnNavigatingTo` and parameters to get the content to show in my cell. Once that happens the cell height has already been determined and it does not fit my content.

```cs
public override void OnNavigatingTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
{
    base.OnNavigatingTo(parameters);

    // Parse parameters for CreateUser, CreateTime, and Description
}
```

[image: screenshot]

I am struggling to come up with a custom renderer that would resolve this problem. Any ideas?